# iAd banner view best practices

Tags: ios, sdk, iad

Apple documents mention this in their iAd best practices section,

> If the user navigates from a screen of content with a banner view to a
>   screen that does not have a banner view, and you expect them to be on
>   that screen for a long period of time, remove the banner view from the
>   view hierarchy, set its delegate to nil and release it before
>   transitioning to the new screen of content. More generally, avoid
>   keeping a banner view around when it is invisible to the user.

I was wondering how do I exactly do this? I have a tabBar application with 2 tabs. And I would like to remove iAd BannerView when 1st tab is not visible. And load it back when it is appeared again. I'm using viewWillAppear to load the add. And trying to remove banner with viewWillDisappear.

I tried to remove bannerView from the view like this,

```
   [[[self.view subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
```

Then it is removed when navigating to the tab 2. But when I tap tab 1 again, banner never loads again.

What is the best way to do this?

Here's viewWillAppear code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    ADBannerView *banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 0, 0)];
    banner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    banner.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:banner];
    [banner release];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use in viewWillAppear¨?

Comment: @HampusNilsson Just edited with that code